# Getting null pointer Exception..?

Tags: java, selenium

```
public WebElement locater(String locter)
    {
        String[] value = locter.split("##");
        String loctValue = value[0];
        String loctType = value[1];



        try {
            if(loctType.equalsIgnoreCase("XP"))
            {


                loct = driver.findElement(By.xpath(loctValue));


            }
            else if(loctType.endsWith("id"))
            {
                loct = driver.findElement(By.id(loctValue));

            }
            else if(loctType.equalsIgnoreCase("linkText"))
            {
                loct = driver.findElement(By.linkText(loctValue));
            }
            else if(loctType.equalsIgnoreCase("partialLink"))
            {
                loct = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText(loctValue));
            }
            else if(loctType.equalsIgnoreCase("cssSelect"))
            {
                loct = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(loctValue));
            }
            else if(loctType.equalsIgnoreCase("name"))
            {
                loct = driver.findElement(By.name(loctValue));
            }
            else if(loctType.equalsIgnoreCase("tagname"))
            {
                loct = driver.findElement(By.tagName(loctValue));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return loct;

    }
```

Unable to resolve...any one can help me out

Comment: and where do you get a NPE?

Answer (score 0):

Please check for `loctType`, `loctValue` is not `null`. And also its good to check `locter` too is `not` null before your `try catch` operation.

Comment: it is printing locvalue and loctype as asked.There is some problem in function callling

Comment: Change this with your values.

Comment: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By
  .xpath(loctValue)));

Comment: Use this for your elements before using findBy.....